# Check a database or check file storage for a name clash?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm keeping a list of my media in a table.

When adding new media, would it be more efficient to check the table for a filename clash, or check the storage?

10,000 or so images/rows.

Comment: Depends _entirely_ on how good the code is you wrote to keep the table in sync with the filesystem? As well as how much RAM you provisioned. As well as the type of disk you're using. As well as the file system you're using. Because your database _can_ be faster than a disk check, or it can be _a lot_ slower. This is one of those classic "do some benchmarking to find out, because this should be easily tested by you, on the actual hardware you're using".

Comment: Table should be more efficient. File won't have indexs. Maybe related https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23124/whats-better-faster-mysql-or-filesystem

Comment: @user3783243 they're called "directory indexes" for a reason.

Comment: @Sammitch My interpretation of this was that it was 1 file with a list of filenames in it. If it is +10k individual files I think that also would have issues (although it might be 100k).

Comment: I/O operations are generally slower than in-memory operations performed by the database.